# Iterating Through Rows when importing Gsheet Worksheets Via Ruby Gem gets "no implicit conversion of String into Integer" error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-sheets, google-drive-api

I'm using the "google_drive" gem to access a Google Sheet worksheet and I've been able to access and print the worksheet, so the API connection is fine.

However, I'm trying to build a method that iterates through every row and find or creates a user based on that.  I've tried these two options:

```
def import
      session = GoogleDrive::Session.from_service_account_key("credspath")
      spreadsheet  = session.spreadsheet_by_title("My Worksheet Title")
      worksheet  = spreadsheet.worksheets.first
      worksheet.rows.each do |row|
        customer = Customer.find_by(email: row['email'])
        if customer.blank?
           customer = Customer.new(email: row['email'] )
           puts "New Customer #{customer.email} "
        end
      end
    end
```

and this

```
def import
      session = GoogleDrive::Session.from_service_account_key("credspath")
      spreadsheet  = session.spreadsheet_by_title("My Worksheet Title")
      worksheet  = spreadsheet.worksheets.first
      CSV.foreach(worksheet, headers: true, encoding:"iso-8859-1:utf-8") do |row|
        customer = Customer.find_by(email: row['email'])
        if customer.blank?
           customer = Customer.new(email: row['email'] )
           puts "New Customer #{customer.email} "
        end
      end
    end
```

I'm getting the error: "no implicit conversion of String into Integer" for the line that the iteration starts on...

How can I create from this API connection WITHOUT exporting to CSV?

Comment: I'm going to take a wild guess and say that `row` is an array and you're trying to index into it as if it were a hash.

Comment: I appreciate this comment @StephenCrosby and I'm learning a lot trying to understand what you're getting at.

Comment: can you please share the sheet?

Comment: @AmitPatel it's not possible to share the actual sheet, but the columns are "email", "full name", "created_at"

Comment: If you want to read the data in the sheet you should be using the google sheets api not the google drive api thats just file storage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reducing your first example to a minimal "cell read", you have:

```rb
worksheet = spreadsheet.worksheets.first
worksheet.rows.each do |row|
  row['email']
end
```

The [README from `google-drive-ruby`](https://github.com/gimite/google-drive-ruby) has a cells and rows access example like this:

```rb
ws = session.spreadsheet_by_key("pz7XtlQC-PYx-jrVMJErTcg").worksheets[0]
p ws.rows  #==> [["fuga", ""], ["foo", "bar]]
```

It's pretty clear that the `#rows` method returns `Array`s, not `Hash`s. What you're doing is:

```rb
row = ["abcd", "xyz"]
row['email'] # will raise TypeError: no implicit conversion of String into Integer
```

`google-drive-ruby` is not loading a "table structure" of headers and rows -- it just has cells of data in a 2D table.

You need to either just access by index: `row[0]`

Or process the table into structured data yourself:

```rb
sheet_header, *sheet_body = sheet.rows
structured_rows = sheet_body.map do |row|
  sheet_header.zip(row).to_h # construct the hash-per-row you wanted
end
```

Comment: Author is using the Google drive api you are using the Google Sheets api you man want to tell them why the should be using a diffrent api.

Comment: Don't understand what you mean. I linked to the information my answer is based on, maybe you can do the same?

Comment: @DaImTo  the Github repo for 'google_drive' gem  is 'google-drive-ruby',  there doesn't seem to be a 'google-drive-ruby' gem...perhaps it was previously called 'google-drive-ruby' but kache's info is accurate

Comment: Many other gems are installed with `google_drive` including `googleauth` and `google-apis-sheets_v4`.